# Is it possible to SET a variable inside a stored procedure so that a view uses it?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a view that depends on a session variable:

```
create or replace view test as 
(
    select getvariable('MY_VAR')::int as col1
) ;
```

I can query that view like this:

```
set MY_VAR=5;
select * from test; -- 5
set MY_VAR=6;
select * from test; -- 6
```

Now I want to do the same query from a stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure myproc()
    returns VARCHAR
    language javascript
    as 
$$
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "select * from test"});
    var rs = stmt.execute();
    rs.next(); // .next().getColumnValue(1);

    return rs.getColumnValue(1);
$$
;

call myproc() -- this work as long as MY_VAR is set outside before the call proc
```

The thing is that I want to set the the session variable from within the procedure and that is not allowed

> Stored procedure execution error: Unsupported statement type 'SET'. At Snowflake.execute

Ultimately the goal is to have a Snowflake TASK that runs the stored procedure and I need to be able to set the variable somehow (the TASK doesn't allow to run set either, and neither does the stored procedure).

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason that you are unable to SET a session variable inside of your stored procedure is that by default, the execution mode is set to **EXECUTE AS OWNER**, which is a more restrictive mode due to security concerns.

Please see this [Snowflake docs page](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#using-session-variables-with-caller-s-rights-and-owner-s-rights-stored-procedures) for more information.

So, you are able to SET (and use) session variable inside of your stored procedure only if you set the execution mode of the stored procedure to **EXECUTE AS CALLER**. Here is a revised version of your stored procedure that demonstrates the use of session variables (using an arbitrary value of 7):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYPROC()
  RETURNS VARCHAR
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS $$
    snowflake.execute({"sqlText": "SET MY_VAR = 7"});
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({"sqlText": "select * from test"});
    var rs = stmt.execute();
    rs.next(); // .next().getColumnValue(1);

    return rs.getColumnValue(1);
$$
;
```